# How to vertically and horizontally center an image in a div

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to center images in divs.

This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="header-item">
    <div style="background-color: gray;" id="tod-header">
        <div>
            <div style="float: left;" id="tod-title">
                <img style="max-width: 400px; height: 134px;" 
                  src="http://i.imgur.com/rJBx6.jpg" alt="A Random Image" />
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; min-height: 134px; padding-left: 50px;">
                <!-- Poor man's separator between columns -->
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; min-height: 134px;">
                <!-- I want to place two divs here..
                 each div will have an image that will be
                 vertically and horizontally centered in the div 
                 -->
                 <div id="callout_1" style="min-height: 134px; float: left;">              
                     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8J4sS.jpg" width=100px />
                 </div>

                 <div id="callout_2" style="min-height: 134px; float: left;" >    
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LtdCR.jpg" width=200px />
                 </div>

            </div>

            <!-- This is a hack to allow gray background to fill header -->
            <div style="min-height: 134px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/7x61fmgt/488/)

How do I get the two images on the right hand side to be centered vertically and horizontally in their respective divs?

Comment: Google: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: [https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/exactly-center-an-imagediv-horizontally-and-vertically/]

Comment: @Paulie_D: It would have been more useful if you included the previously asked question of which this is a duplicate, since I clearly did not know about it, and I (obviously?) already know how to ask/edit questions on here....

Comment: @UpendrasinhJadeja: It's generally considered good practice to check if a link exists before posting it as a recommendation.

Comment: @Homunculus Reticulli if you know it all, why ask the question in the first place? No need to get patronizing.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Did you check the top of the page...the duplicate link is there.